# Search and replace the selected filepath in vim

Tags: vim, replace

I often work with files full of filepaths inside. I want to be able to quickly select my filepath in Visual Mode and replace it with some other filepath.

For example I have the file like this:

```
balvadsd /mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe blablabalba albla
/mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe bla2 vslva 21 
stuff foo bar dsad /mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe
```

I need to

1. search for all occurrences of `/mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe`
2. replace my path `/mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe` with some other path. The tricky bit is that the solutions like [this one](http://asktherelic.com/2011/04/02/on-easily-replacing-text-in-vim/) don't work with filepaths because of slashes, backslashes and dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the regex metacharacters with `\`. So `foo/bar` becomes `foo\/bar` for your regex. Or you can use a different seperator like `#`. However you still need escape the `.`. You can avoid the need to escape `.` and other regex metacharacters by using `\V` for very nomagic. Using `\V` means all regex metacharacters now must be escaped meaning non escaped charters match their literal selves.

```
:%s#\V/mnt/Windows/Documents\ and\ Settings/stuff/file.exe#replacement#g
```

However all that escaping can become annoying. I usually use a visual star mapping and/or [plugin](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search). Meaning I visually select the text then press `*`. Then you can just do `:%s//replacement/` or `:%s##replacement#` to make the replacement.

There are some nice [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes by Neil Drew that talk about this:

- [Search for the selected text](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-for-the-selected-text/)
- [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/).

You can take this idea further with the `gn` motion and the `.` command. See the following vimcast episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/).

For more help see:

```
:h /\V
:h gn
```

Comment: I don't understand the part where you visually select the text and then press `*`. I've selected my file path in Visual Mode and pressed `*`. It seems that `*` worked only for one word in file path, not for the whole file path. And `*` just expanded the Visual Mode selection. How exactly do you use it?

Comment: @ganqqwerty I think you are missing the part where I use a mapping or plugin. Here is a mapping I have used in the past: `xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'\'),'/','\="\\%d".char2nr(submatch(0))','g')<cr><cr>` However I prefer to go the plugin route

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using slashes in the body of the substitute command you can use **any other** single-byte character, but **not** an alphanumeric character, '\', '"' or '|'. (in this example @).

`%s@/mnt/Windows/Documents\\@/some/other/path`