# Vim search & replace (all) from text selected in visual mode

Tags: vim

I'm curious if it's possible, using Vim, to engage a search & replace based on text selected in Visual mode?

For example, if I have `public int Id;` selected in visual mode. Is it possible to perform a search & replace (all instances) without having to retype `public int Id;` into the `:s[ubtitute]/{pattern}/{string}` command?

Answer (score 1):

Use such mapping:

```
 vnoremap <Leader>zr :<c-u>%s/<c-r>*
```

Selected text is in the selection buffer already, so we paste it with ^r*

`<c-u>` cleans the command prompt

Comment: This relies on the `*` register which will work great for X11, but not necessarily all systems and may changed based on the value of `'clipboard'`. A similar (yet naive) approach would be to do `xnoremap <leader>zr y:%s/<c-r>"/`. This does not account for any escaping though. Personally, I would also recommend a [visual-star plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=star) or using `xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>`. See [Search and replace the selected filepath in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24914432/438329).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look with this vim plugin [terryma/vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).
For your case, just select that blocks, then press  several times, there'll be several cursors highlight those blocks, you could edit time at the same time.